# C# 8 positional pattern vs. deconstruction pattern

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

In the first proposal of pattern matching the recursive pattern was defined with the following grammar:

```
recursive_pattern
    : positional_pattern
    | property_pattern
    ;
```

Link: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/patterns.md
To demonstrate the positional pattern, .Net team has use the Cartesian exmaple which override the is opreator:

```
public static bool operator is(Cartesian c, out double R, out double Theta)
```

Note: I know that the 'is' opreator cannot be overridden in C#

in the other specification:
https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1054

```
Recursive pattern matching defined like the following:
    pattern
        : declaration_pattern
        | constant_pattern
        | deconstruction_pattern
        | property_pattern
        ;
```

When I test the pattern matching(abovementioned) with following Link:
https://sharplab.io

Deconstruction pattern working fine but positional pattern not (I cannot override the is opreator as described in the positional pattern proposal example )

MY question:

What is the different between positional pattern and deconstruction pattern?

The working Code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var stratec = new Company
      {
        Name = "stratec",
        Website = "wwww.stratec.com",
        HeadOfficeAddress = "Birkenfeld",
      };

      var firstEmploy = new Employ { Name = "Bassam Alugili", Age = 42, Company = stratec };

      var microsoft = new Company
      {
        Name = "microsoft",
        Website = "www.microsoft.com",
        HeadOfficeAddress = "Redmond, Washington",
      };

      var thidEmploy = new Employ { Name = "Satya Nadella", Age = 52, Company = microsoft };


      DumpEmploy(firstEmploy);
    }

    public static void DumpEmploy(Employ employ)
    {
      switch (employ)
      {

         case Employ{Name:"Bassam Alugili", Company:Company(_,_,_)} employTmp:
          {
            Console.WriteLine($"The employ:  {employTmp.Name}! 1");
          }
          break;


        default:
          Console.WriteLine("Unknow company!");
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}


public class Company
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Website { get; set; }

  public string HeadOfficeAddress { get; set; }

  public void Deconstruct(out string name, out string website, out string headOfficeAddress)
  {
    name = Name;
    website = Website;
    headOfficeAddress = HeadOfficeAddress;
  }
}

public class Employ
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public int Age { get; set; }

  public Company Company { get; set; }


  public void Deconstruct(out string name, out int age, out Company company)
  {
    name = Name;
    age = Age;
    company = Company;
  }
}
```

How can I modifiy the code to test the positional pattern!?

[image]

this is the link: you can also copy and paste the code you will get the same result:

[Sharplab link with code](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: Yes, but after you've added code at Sharplab, notice that the url has changed, it contains a blob with that code, so you can copy and add a link with all that and we can click directly to sharplab *with* the code.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post an example link in comment as it is far too long but perhaps you can in the question.

Comment: Example with different code: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLRIMaOQSwG4SoAOsMECAdsgDQAmIA1AD4ACADAAQsCMA3ALAAoIRSgBbFCQwQOAYQD2VeQBsIAQSJEATEIDeQjly1duAdgMd9gw4Z4A2LgBYTADgAUPNgG0AuhygIAObIAJQWhlY2USYAnG4ARAAqKDDxIQLWNgC+FjmCeUA=

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of documents being out-of-date and/or unclear. "positional" and "deconstruction" are synonyms, which both refer to a parenthesized list of sub-patterns.

The latest grammar is described in https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/features/recursive-patterns/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Syntax/Syntax.xml#L1816

A recursive pattern has an optional type, an optional deconstruction pattern clause (also called positional pattern clause), an optional property pattern clause and an optional designation.

There are semantic rules restricting usage (for example, you can't have a pattern where all the optional parts are omitted at once).

A deconstruction pattern clause is a parenthesized list of sub-patterns, which are patterns with an optional name-colon.